# csharp cygwin can not kill mintty.exe

Tags: c#, process, cygwin, system.diagnostics

I was working with the `Process` class from `System.Diagnostics` and here is my code:

```
public void doMain() {
    Process cygwin = new Process();
    cygwin.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\mintty.exe";
    cygwin.Start();
    cygwin.Refresh();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    cygwin.Kill();
    cygwin.WaitForExit();
}
```

Typically this should run `mintty.exe` process and then wait 1 seconds and then kill that process but it gives me the error that it has been closed before the kill call.

On the line `cygwin.Kill();` call this exception occurs:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll
>   Additional information: Cannot process request because the process has exited.

Why is this happening?!
If I replace the `"C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\mintty.exe"` with `"C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe"` the exception goes away!
What is the problem?

Comment: If you run `mintty.exe` from `file explorer` rather than in code, does it immediately exit? I have a feeling `bash.exe` provides you with a command line utility when you load it, but `mintty` has no such thing.

Comment: @JayGould No! why it should immediately exit? I made my code to wait for `1000` milliseconds and then kill the process. Well `mintty.exe` is somehow like a wrapper for `bash.exe`.

Comment: First, ask yourself what that error/exception means during execution of the kill method. As I read it, kill is failing because the process you are trying to kill has already exited. Read my answer down below. The Start methed creates process #p which forks to create child process #c. Process #p exits. Process #c opens the mintty window. You try to kill process #p, but it is already killed/exited. What is the process number in the cygwin object? What is the process number(s) of mintty (hint: use task manager)?

Comment: @DougHenderson yeah they are different, your right.

Comment: @DougHenderson so do you think is there any way to get mintty process under control?

Comment: Not easily. Perhaps you need another solution. Why do you want to start mintty and later kill it? Are you trying to run a cygwin shell script? Maybe that script will run correctly if you start bash in a command window. Maybe it will run if you start bash directly to execute the script and send output back to your C# app. [If at First You Don’t Succeed then Maybe You’re Doing it Wrong](https://marthawills.com/2012/12/06/if-at-first-you-dont-succeed-then-maybe-youre-doing-it-wrong/)

Comment: @DougHenderson yeah, actually my intention is redirect I/O of mintty.exe but if I cant kill it, then I dont have access to it, right?!  btw good quote thanks.

Comment: I think you will find that mintty has no output streams. Sounds like you might need to run bash directly and capture its output streams.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `cygwin.WaitForExit()` after already killing the process, hence the error.

Update your code to:

```
public void doMain() {
    Process cygwin = new Process();
    cygwin.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\mintty.exe";
    cygwin.Start();
    cygwin.Refresh();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    cygwin.Kill();
    //cygwin.WaitForExit();
}
```

and it should work.

Comment: Not working again after commenting that line. Also read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill(v=vs.110).aspx It says `The Kill method executes asynchronously. After calling the Kill method, call the WaitForExit method to wait for the process to exit, or check the HasExited property to determine if the process has exited.`

Comment: Which line is the error happening on? You say "after this", does `WaitForExit()` get invoked or not?

Comment: I think it does not get invoked. by after I meant `on` the line.

Answer (score 0):

This is the bog simple way of starting a windows program that is independent from the starting process and method. The program forks (starts a new process) immediately, and that new child opens the mintty window, while the original process exits. This is designed to prevent you from doing what you are trying to do. It creates the child in a new process tree. Otherwise, if you ran the program from a cmd window, it would close when you close the cmd window.

Comment: I opened cmd and entered `cd "c:/cygwin64/bin"` followed by `mintty.exe` the cygwin window opens but it does not get closed when I close the cmd window. Aside from this, I think all those `Process` class does is forking right? cause if it have used `exec` I would have been seeing my winform (that code was part of a gui app bound to click method of hitting a button) get closed, true? correct me please if im wrong. thanks :)